# Where to put miscellaneous files, scripts within a React folder structure?

Tags: python, r, reactjs, directory, scripting

(I apologize if this is a silly question, but there are common standards for this in R and python...I don't know about React.)

I'm building a React application, and I've been trying to use the canonical folder structure used by others.

For this project, I've parsed some *csv files using python scripts and R scripts. I'm using something like the following:

```
/react-app
  /build
  /node_modules
  /public
  /src
    /assets
    /components
    /contexts
    /lib
    /pages
    /services
    /styles
    AppRoutes.tsx
    index.tsx
    react-app-env.d.ts

  package.json
  README.md
  tsconfig.json
  yarn.lock
```

Is there a canonical folder to place scripts and data? Where should I store it, so that other users realize these are scripts used to create the input data for the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no "canonical" place as far as i know; i've seen people put a `scripts/` folder at the root which seems like the most straightforward option. there are many ways to organize a react app-- I wouldn't overthink it